# jQuery click brings me to top of page but I need to stay where I im

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, preventdefault

I have this code:

```
$('.bidbutton').on( "click", function() {

    $('.addOffer').hide();

    $('.preko').show();
        var i = $(this).attr('klik');   
      $('.i'+i).hide();
      $('.j'+i).show();
 });
```

Now when I click jquery bring me to the top of page but I need to stay where I am.

I try

```
$('.bidbutton').on( "click", function() {

    $('.addOffer').hide();

    $('.preko').show();
        var i = $(this).attr('klik');   
      $('.i'+i).hide();
      $('.j'+i).show();
      evt.preventDefault();
 });
```

but dont work...
How to solve this problem?

**QUestion update:**

```
<div class="row preko i2" index="2" style="border-bottom-width: 5px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: none;">
   <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2" style=" background: #f4f4f4; ">
      <h3 class="text-center">20.</h3>
      <p class="text-center">Apr</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8 text-center">
      <h3>$55</h3>
      <p>current bid</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2" style=" margin-top: 25px; "> <a href="#" klik="2" class="btn btn-info btn-lg bidbutton pull-right">Bid Now</a> </div>
</div>
<div class="row addOffer j2" style="display: block;" index="2">
   <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2" style=" background: #f4f4f4; ">
      <h3 class="text-center">20.</h3>
      <p class="text-center">Apr</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-10" style="margin-top:10px;">
      <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8888/offers" id="target" accept-charset="UTF-8">
         <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="BWSwRnV8diq3QEF5FKcRa0ThWpBODKSMAlwEWZEH"><input name="article_id" type="hidden" value="8"><input name="start" class="hstart" type="hidden" value="04/20/2016 12:00 am"><input name="provera" class="provera" type="hidden" value="522">
         <div class="input-group bootstrap-touchspin" style="padding:10px;">
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default bootstrap-touchspin-down" type="button">-</button></span><span class="input-group-addon bootstrap-touchspin-prefix" style="display: none;"></span><input id="price" type="text" class="form-control price input-lg" name="price" value="55" style="display: block;"><span class="input-group-addon bootstrap-touchspin-postfix" style="display: none;"></span>
            <div class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default bootstrap-touchspin-up" type="button">+</button><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info input-lg okvir">PLACE BID</button></div>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my update to question with html code...

Comment: You'll need to pass `evt` to your function. E.g. `$('.bidbutton').on( "click", function(evt) {`. See [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/). It might be helpful if you include your HTML to show us a working example.

Comment: yes thats the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your event handler function for the `click` event listener is missing the first argument, which is the [jQuery Event Object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).  You need to change your function to:

```
$('.bidbutton').on( "click", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // do stuff
}
```

Here are the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/click/) on the `.click()` event listener.  Pay attention to the handler function format.

The `eventObject` argument is optional on a handler function except when you actually need to do something with the event.  You can assign the `eventObject` to any value you want, and you will often see `e`, `evt`, or `event` in code examples.  In the case of your particular button, I'm assuming this is the `.bidbutton` element you're assigning the click handler to:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info input-lg okvir">PLACE BID</button>
```

Since this `button` has `type="submit"`, it is submitting the form and reloading the page.  By adding `evt.preventDefault()` you are changing this behavior, but this also means you will need to use JavaScript to submit your form to your server.  Reference the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) on `jQuery.ajax()` to do this or [MDN's guide to Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Comment: It would also be useful to highlight why he needs to do that.

Comment: I agree it would be useful but without further context on what that button does by default, I don't actually know why default needs to be prevented.

Comment: Its because if the button is of type submit, it would post the form to the server. This is the default behavior of that button. Preventdefault basically prevents that behavior.

Comment: Right. That is most likely the reason but without the HTML I don't know that for sure. But I agree it still is a useful addition to the answer.

Comment: Edited to include information on why to use `evt.preventDeffault()` & how to submit your form in the background with JS

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass `evt` to the function like so:

```
function(evt)
```